# How the check table access patterns on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a fairly large table (250 M rows growing with 50-60 k rows a day) and am looking for the best way to check *how the table is accessed*.

The idea is to identify the slowest queries on that table to either:

1. add indexes
2. inform the users to rewrite their queries

I'm running version 13.6, and have been creating a pgbadger report, however the table is not in the TOP N slowest queries.

Is there a way to run pgbadger report (or similar) on an individual table? If what, what is the recommended workflow to do this analysis?

Comment: Use auto_explain (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) to log the plans of the slow queries.

Comment: " the table is not in the TOP N slowest queries."  So either your N is too small, or you don't have a problem in the first place.

Comment: To compliment jjanes last point, it doesn't make a ton of sense to look for slow queries by a specific table, as that table might not be a problem at all. A large table doesn't necessarily mean your processes on that table will be slow. It's more sensible to just start with looking for your slow queries and deducing the bottlenecks of those queries themselves which many times aren't even the table's fault.

Comment: I recommend using `pg_stat_statements` to analyze the workload. That will tell you which statements using that table are problematic.